# Insert phone into Cardboard holder in oculus quest

Tags: android, android-studio, capacitor, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am trying to run an aframe file on Android Studio When I try going into VR mode in Oculus Quest (clicking on the cardboard icon in the bottom right corner) I get the message "Insert phone into Cardboard holder".

I can't find a way to get past the message. How to create an app suitable for Oculus Quest using android studio?

When I press the "X" icon it just goes back to standard 3D mode (not split screen).

## Manifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking" android:required="true"
    android:version="24" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
            <category android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->
```

---

### activity main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

- 